# Using DELETE with an INNER JOIN

Tags: php, sql

I would like to be able to delete companies and all its users from a page.

So I did the following:

```
$removeid = $_POST['removeid'];

$deletecompany = "
DELETE c,u 
FROM company c 
INNER JOIN users u 
ON c.id = u.id_company 
WHERE c.id = ".$removeid."";
$deletecompanycon = $conn->query($deletecompany);
```

This only works when a company has users, but when there is only a company and no users attached to it, the query still goes through but the company is not deleted.

How can I make sure a company is deleted even if there are no users?

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using LEFT JOIN

```
$deletecompany = "
DELETE c,u 
FROM company c 
LEFT JOIN users u 
ON c.id = u.id_company 
WHERE c.id = ".$removeid."";
$deletecompanycon = $conn->query($deletecompany);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, and I will improve security after above tips. - I can accept your answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: You may also do it in two steps: first, delete the users given a company id ; second: delete the company. And place these two steps inside a transaction. Unless there is a specific business needs, or a technical impossibility to do otherwise (such as performance or cyclomatic complexity), one should favor simpler, flatter queries.

Comment: You're welcome twan. Notice that I only mark what was wrong in your query. Like Gabriel said, probably it's not the best solution, it depends of your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option to the foreign key constraint in `users`. Then all users of a company get deleted if the company is deleted, by the DBMS.

It looks similar to this in a `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE users
       (...
        FOREIGN KEY (id_company)
                    REFERENCES company
                               (id)
                    ON DELETE CASCADE,
        ...);
```

You have to look up how it exactly can be added to an existing constraint in your DBMS. The syntax can quite vary here.